# How to pass message between client & server over the web using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I heard SignalR is a good messaging library. I got some code for SignalR but I am not able to understand how it works.

JS

```
var hooking;
$(function() {

  hooking = $.connection.hooking;
  hooking.removeLead = function(ref) {
    $("lead" + ref).remove();
  };

  $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

C#

```
// Hooking.cs (placed in application root)
public class Hooking : Hub
{
  public void Submit(string jsonString)
  {
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Deserialize<HookingLeadResult>(jsonString);
    Clients.removeLead(json.Ref); // Remove lead from client hooking windows
    // update lead gen
  }
}
```

I have questions about the above code.

- What does `hooking` mean ins **`$.connection.hooking;`**
- Where is `removeLead` in **`hooking.removeLead`**
- What will this do **`$.connection.hub.start();`** ? What does it start? Which method it will invoke at the server side?
- Who & how `Submit` method will be called at the server side? how to pass data from client side to server side. If possible please give me a url for good start for SignalR library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript function `hooking.removeLead` will be invoked whenever you call `Clients.removeLead()`. All the bindings are done dynamically, between Javascript to C# and between C# and Javascript.

`$.connection.hub.start()` is actually the connect function. It will connect your client to the server. No messages can be sent or received until you do. The `start` function allows you to define a callback to be called when it's done connecting.

The `Submit` method at the server will be called whenever you do a `hooking.submit(json)` call on your client. For instance, as a result of the user filling in some form and clicking a button.

I recommend starting with the SignalR official wiki: http://www.asp.net/signalr